# NSArray create with some elements plus another NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, realm

I am trying to use model inheritance on [[image]realm](/questions/tagged/realm). So I minded up using the code below to override and also call `super` method.

```
+ (NSArray *)requiredProperties {
    return @[[super requiredProperties], @"thisIsRequired",@"thisIsAlsoRequired"];
}
```

So the question: is it OK to create an `NSArray` on the fly while also using another `NSArray` and some more elements:

```
NSArray *mySecondArray = @[myFirstArray, @"andSomeExtras", @"alsoMoreExtras"];
```

What I have been expecting is; first element of `mySecondArray` should be the first element of `myFirstArray`. Second element of `mySecondArray` should be the second element of `myFirstArray` and so on. (size of `myFirstArray`) +1 th element of `mySecondArray` should be `@"thisIsRequired"` .

Or I am making up some kind of magix?

Well, as you can see I am new to the stuff and I might be confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is okay to instantiate such heterogeneous arrays with Foundation. It's just not what you want here. In your example, you would end up with the following instead:

```
NSArray *myFirstArray = @[@"firstsFirstsElement", @"firstsSecondElement"];
NSArray *mySecondArray = @[myFirstArray, @"andSomeExtras", @"alsoMoreExtras"];
/* => 
@[
  @[@"firstsFirstsElement", @"firstsSecondElement"],
  @"andSomeExtras",
  @"alsoMoreExtras",
]
*/
```

You're looking for [`- arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:). You can use it like seen below:

```
+ (NSArray *)requiredProperties {
    return [super.requiredProperties arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[
         @"thisIsRequired",
         @"thisIsAlsoRequired",
    ]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is Ok**, as long as you will remember what you are doing anywhere in your code.
However you usually reserve the use of `NSArray` for a homogeneous collection of objects and use `NSDictionary`, or better your own [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) class, for heterogeneous aggregation of data.

---

`NSArray` official documentation show a similar example in the section dedicated to the method [arrayWithObjects:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObjects:)

`NSArray` is really an array of `id`, even with [generics](http://www.miqu.me/blog/2015/06/09/adopting-objectivec-generics/) enabled.

---

This other link about [Objective C generics](http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/) may also help understand the nature of the raw `NSArray` class.

Comment: So, if I am correct; first element of `mySecondArray` will be `myFirstArray`. What I was expecting is:  first element of `mySecondArray` should be first element of `myFirstArray`.

Comment: Yes, `NSArray` contains objects. `myFirstArray` is an object, the `@` is a syntax sugar to make a `NSString` out of a C literal string. Everything is an object, there is nothing special with your line of code. You can do that in obj-c.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use NSMutableArray and just add the objects?

```
NSMutableArray *mySecondArray = [myFirstArray mutableCopy];
[mySecondArray addObject:@"andSomeExtras"];
[mySecondArray addObject:@"alsoMoreExtras"];
```

Comment: That is doable, but I have searched for a shortcut.

Comment: Unless you want to add more objects to the array later, there is no need to use a mutable array. The syntax sugar for literals is short and easy. And immutability is good.